# Comparing two columns and if it matches both the columns should be highlighted

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns J and L.

If the value of J column matches with the corresponding value of L column, both the cells should be highlighted in red.

I am new to this Excel. I am not able to develop this macro.

I tried the below code but it is highlighting J, K and L column if it matches I want only the J and K column to be highlighted and also this macro should start checking from J11 and L11

```
Sub test()    
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")    
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row    
        arr = .Range("J2" & ":L" & LastRow)

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)    
            If arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 3) Then    
                .Range("J" & i + 1 & ":L" & i + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed    
            End If    
        Next i    
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: There is an option on conditional formatting for spotting duplicates. Could that be of use to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if is this what u want

```
Sub test()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        arr = .Range("J11" & ":L" & LastRow)

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 3) Then
                .Range("J" & i + 10 & ":J" & i + 10).Interior.Color = vbRed
                .Range("L" & i + 10 & ":L" & i + 10).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

it starts checking from line 11

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the desired output:

```
Sub test()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        arr = .Range("J2" & ":L" & LastRow)

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 3) Then
                .Range("J" & i + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                .Range("L" & i + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Just take them separately.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the range with data
2. Home - Styles - Conditional Formatting
3. New Rule - Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4. Format values where this formula is true:

   `=$J1=$L1`
5. Format - Fill - select your color
6. Change Applies to (the area where the formatting will apply)

**Rule:**

[image]

**Results:**

[image]